# How do I split a table of orders into a header table and a details table using a stored process?

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on MS SQL Server. I have a table (allOrders) with orders that are being uploaded to the database. There are multiple rows per order. All rows from the same order have the same order number. I need to make two new tables from this, one with the order header(headerTable) and one with the order details(detailsTable). I have a processed_state variable to track if the order has been processed yet. I need to be able to split the orders that are coming in to the table multiple times a day, so the solution needs to be an automatable one. The part I am struggling with is splitting each order into a header and details. For example the header needs to have the OrderNo, Total Price, Customer, Order Date and Delivery Date and the details needs to have the OrderNo, each Product, Price, Customer and Delivery Date. This is an example of what I need:

```
allOrders
OrderNo|Product|Quantity|Price|Product Code|Customer|Order Date|Delivery Date|Processed State
1000   |Chips  |3       |2    |908         |Shop1   |12-09-2019|15-09-2019   |0
1000   |Sweets |5       |6    |5904        |Shop1   |12-09-2019|15-09-2019   |0
1000   |Soda   |2       |1    |90          |Shop1   |12-09-2019|15-09-2019   |0
1001   |Chips  |5       |2    |908         |Shop2   |12-09-2019|16-09-2019   |0
1001   |Sweets |5       |6    |5904        |Shop2   |12-09-2019|15-09-2019   |0
1002   |Chips  |3       |2    |908         |Shop1   |19-09-2019|21-09-2019   |0
1002   |Sweets |5       |6    |5904        |Shop1   |19-09-2019|21-09-2019   |0

headerTable
OrderNo|Total Price|Customer|Order Date|Delivery Date
1000   |38         |Shop1   |12-09-2019|15-09-2019
1001   |40         |Shop2   |12-09-2019|16-09-2019
1002   |36         |Shop1   |19-09-2019|21-09-2019

detailsTable
OrderNo|Product|Quantity|Price|Product Code|Customer|Delivery Date
1000   |Chips  |3       |2    |908         |Shop1   |15-09-2019   
1000   |Sweets |5       |6    |5904        |Shop1   |15-09-2019   
1000   |Soda   |2       |1    |90          |Shop1   |15-09-2019   
1001   |Chips  |5       |2    |908         |Shop2   |16-09-2019   
1001   |Sweets |5       |6    |5904        |Shop2   |15-09-2019   
1002   |Chips  |3       |2    |908         |Shop1   |21-09-2019   
1002   |Sweets |5       |6    |5904        |Shop1   |21-09-2019
```

I tried inserting using `select distinct` but could not get that to work, and I also tried `select top 1` but could not work out how to select the top 1 from each order. The main issue is making it repeatable, so it needs to work off changing the Processed State to 1 once the order has been split.

Comment: *"I tried inserting using select distinct but could not get that to work, and I also tried select top 1 but could not work out how to select the top 1 from each order."* if you don't show us those attempts it's very difficult to explain why they didn't work.

Comment: I mean that I could not get a statement the worked. I need something like `SELECT OrderNo, Total Price, Customer, Order Date Delivery Date WITH DISTINCT OrderNo`, to select one row from each order for the header, but that statement does not make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your table structure is similar to the allOrders table as you have described above.

Table Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[allOrders] (
[OrderNo] int NOT NULL,
[Product] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
[Quantity] int NOT NULL,
[Price] decimal(18, 2) NOT NULL,
[ProductCode] varchar(50) NOT NULL,
[Customer] varchar(50) NOT NULL,
[OrderDate] date NOT NULL,
[DeliveryDate] date NOT NULL,
[ProcessedFlag] bit NOT NULL)
ON [PRIMARY]
WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = NONE);
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[allOrders] SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE);
GO
```

Then proceed with inserting your data as you have provided above.

The following queries below would answer your question.

```
-- Header
SELECT OrderNo, SUM(Quantity * Price) as 'TOTAL_PRICE', Customer, OrderDate, DeliveryDate
FROM TestOrders
GROUP BY OrderNo, Customer, OrderDate, DeliveryDate
ORDER BY OrderNo ASC;

-- Details
SELECT OrderNo, Product, Quantity, Price, ProductCode, Customer, DeliveryDate
FROM TestOrders
ORDER BY OrderNo ASC, Product ASC
```

Note that for the headers, you need to ensure that the OrderDate and DeliveryDate columns would be the same for each order. Having a different value for the same order number would result in your header query displaying the distinct grouped data (through the date).

Answer (score 0):

For the headerTable do this...

```
select OrderNo, Sum(Quantity * Price) as [Total Price], 
Customer, [Order Date], MAX([Delivery Date]) AS [Delivery Date]
from allOrders
group by  OrderNo, Customer, [Order Date], [Delivery Date]
```

For the detailsTable just select the columns you want from allOrders.

Here is the [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6a20c66d5dd9e6f1bf01da7a1a611cf1).